# ImageMagick: Determining Pixel Aspect Ratio

Tags: imagemagick, tiff

I'm trying to determine the Pixel Aspect Ratio (PAR) of a given image and am trying to use Imagemagick:

```
magick.exe c:\tmp\foo.0001.tif -format "%[fx:w/h]\n" info:
```

This gives me the aspect ratio of the image, though not the Pixel Aspect Ratio. From some digging, it looks like ImageMagick may not be able to do this, but I don't have a definitive answer. Is this possible? Or is there another tool I can use?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, but you can try `magick identify -verbose yourImage.tif` and see if it lists anything likely looking.

Comment: Post a TIFF image so we can see what is going on. Perhaps one can use the width, height, density, units and resolution to compute what you want.

Comment: Here is an upload: https://imgur.com/hPq53nZ

Comment: Mmmm, that's a PNG file I think - not a TIFF.

Comment: Ah nuts, it was a TIFF before I uploaded it. Is there a better imagehosting site?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Please move your response to the answer, that's what I ended up using.

Comment: I think Fred's answer is probably spot on, and have voted for that as the one to go with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ImageMagick, this should do what you want:

```
magick input.tif -format "%[fx:resolution.x/resolution.y]" info:
```